# Find if object belongs to class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, game-engine

I'm trying to make my own CBGE (Component Based Game Engine) in C++ but i am stuck at this question: How to i find if an Object belongs a specific class? Or equivalent with pointers, how do i find if an pointer points to an object of a specific class? Let me give an example:

I have this somewhere in my code:

```
//ComponentManager.h
...
std::map<rUUID, std::vector<Component*>> bucket;
...
```

where rUUID is a class that represents an UUID and Component is an abstract class that
represents all type of components an Entity can have.

Now how can i get a specific type of Component (e.x. PositionComponent) for a given rUUID?

Also can somebody tell me if this type of design is good or bad practice and if so how
should it be formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class `Foo` has some virtual methods and if your compiler supports [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTTI) you could check `dynamic_cast<Foo*>(p) != NULL` to check if `p` points to some instance of `Foo` (assuming that `p` is declared as a pointer`Bar *p;` to some super-class `Bar` of `Foo`)

Notice: `dynamic_cast<Foo*>(p) != NULL` will return `true` if `p` is pointing to an instance of some sub-class of `Foo`.

See also [`<typeinfo>` header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/) and `typeid` (as suggested by [BlackMamba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223579/blackmamba) in another answer).

Answer (score 1):

RTTI works very well, but I want to show one more way.

As I see, all of your instances belong to the Component-class. In this case you can create your own virtual method inside of Component for your own use. Like this:

```
class Component
{
    virtual std::string
    type() const = 0;
};

class someComponent : public Component
{
    virtual std::string
    type() const { return "someComponent"; }
};
```

By this way you can get extra advantages. For instance, make the same types for completely different classes. Or, do more complex action than just return type. And your compiler doesn't have to have RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe，you can use this function: typeid()